# php mail в письме пропадают атрибуты ( WP )

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Отправляю из админки внутри WordPress.
Заголовки

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
```

В  пропадает href, style. ( Теги остаются )
В mail передаю переменную из $_REQUEST ( textarea ), с переменной все в порядке, проверял. НО если задать в mail константную строку, работает нормально. Подскажите как решить проблему. Заранее спасибо.
(wp_mail не работает, поэтому использую mail)

```
function report_product_update( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    if($post->post_type != "product") return;
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['_waitlist_report'] ) ) {
        $emails = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'report_emails', true );
        $emails = explode( ',', $emails );
        $result = 0;

        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"."\r\n";

        $message = $_REQUEST['_waitlist_email'];

        $title = $_REQUEST['_waitlist_title'];

        //$message = '<a href="http://google.com">SomeLink3</a>';
        for( $i=0;$i<count($emails);$i++){
            $result += mail(
                $emails[$i],
                $title,
                $message, 
                $headers
            );
        }
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'waitlist_report', $result . ' ||| ' . $message );
    } else {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'waitlist_report', '0' );
    }
}
```

Comment: сейчас не знаю, но еще недавно письма были больной темой - одни почтовые сервера это не поддерживают, другие это. Чтобы отображалось более-менее в большинстве почтовиков, приходилось писать чуть ли не на html1. Вы на какой почте проверяли? Может это почтовый сервер все вырезает?

Comment: @BOPOH , как я писал, если передать не переменную а сразу строку с ссылкой в параметры, ссылка приходит. Что-то на стороне кода не так.

Comment: а, я не так вас понял, ну тогда надо код показывать, как переменные добавляете, если проблема в коде, то без кода ничего сказать нельзя

Comment: @BOPOH добавил код

Comment: а что в `$message` находится? у вас именно этот код? или вы вырезку привели, чтобы здесь показать? Может это вы сами где-то вырезаете лишнее? Посмотрите что хранится в `$message` после того, как вы его заполнили значением `$_REQUEST['_waitlist_email']` и что находится в нем перед отправкой почты. Вы говорите "работает" - это если вместо `$message` вы напрямую вставляете то, что там должно храниться? Ну значит и правда вы сами вырезаете это, смотрите где значение $message меняется

Comment: @BOPOH Я бы не писал сюда если бы все было так просто) В $message код с тегами, это точно.

Comment: не поверю пока сам не увижу, т.к. сам не увижу, то смотреть придется вам: вставляете перед отправкой логи и смотрите что действительно отправляете. Затем создаете отдельный файл, где только отправка почты (т.е. `$email = ...; $title = ...; ... mail($email, $title...)` где параметры указываете те, что сохранили) Если в этом файле у вас тоже не будет работать как надо - тогда можно будет написать в вопросе этот пример (только надо будет привести и рабочий пример, раз у вас-таки как-то отправляется) Но скорее всего у вас просто при отправке не те параметры заданы

Comment: @BOPOH , говорю, с параметрами там все ок. Если заголовок указать text/plain, приходят теги с аттрибутами.

Comment: приведите тогда то, что отправляете, но не приходит + то, что отправляете и приходит (я про [этот коммент](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476929/#comment542815_476929) говорю) Там может, правда, почтовик вырезает то, что ему не нравится

Comment: @BOPOH 
На входе <a href="http://moy-talisman.ru/magazin/muzyka-om/"> Some link </a>
На выходе <a target="_blank"> Some link </a>

Comment: Я сделал еще несколько тестов - все указывает на то что аттрибуты убираются уже после вызова функции mail, и это на стороне сервера. Видимо какие-то настройки. Но при этом плагин Contact Form 7 работает нормально...

Comment: Так вы же говорите, что если строкой вставляете, то все нормально отправляется. Или вы это про text/plain говорили? т.е. остальное все то же самое, просто поменялся Content-type

Comment: Если передаю строку как аргумент, то да - нормально. Если перезаписываю $message перед отправкой на константную строку то тоже нормально.

Comment: вы это в вопросе кодом укажите, судя по описанию это все-таки вы что-то не так делаете. Т.е. два примера - один не рабочий (с указанием значения $message) и второй рабочий

Comment: @BOPOH обновил пост. Если расскоментировать строку , ссылка будет. Если выслать ту же строку через textarea, нет. $message я записываю в мета поле так что я точно могу сказать что $message получает строку с атрибутами.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо применить функцию

```
stripslashes
```

к тексту сообщения. [Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416567/html-attributes-missing-in-sending-email/34416755)